# Restate parent variable PHP

Tags: php, variables

Instead of restating the parent variable inside itself (`$username`), is there some other way to do it?

```
$username = ($profile_is_admin == true) ? $username . $admin_symbol : $username;
```

Comment: `== true` is redundant and pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this?

```
$username .= ($profile_is_admin) ? $admin_symbol : '';
```

Comment: Be sure to see @deceze's answer - in most cases it really is the better solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15049854/1270996

Answer (score 7):

```
if ($profile_is_admin) {
    $username .= $admin_symbol;
}
```

Comment: +1 It's easy to miss the simplicity in what he was actually trying to do with such complicated code.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
$username .= ($profile_is_admin == true) ? $admin_symbol : '';
```